# Consultar a la base de datos cuando WHERE sea lo que yo le mande desde el controlador de Angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Tengo un **conection.php** que conecta a la DB y  **consultaTickets.php**:

```
<?php  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
date_default_timezone_set("Chile/Continental");

**// Including database connections**  
require_once 'conection.php';

**// mysqli query to fetch all data from database**    
$query = "SELECT rut, numero FROM Tickets WHERE servicio_id = $_POST['servicio_id']";  
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
$arr = array();  

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
$arr[] = $row;  
}  
}  
**// Return json array containing data from the databasecon**  
echo $json_info = json_encode($arr);  
?>
```

El problema lo tengo en la **Query** en el `WHERE` porque deseo mandarle el parámetro desde el controlador de AngularJS porque so datos que obtengo de un login... (otro WS).

La pregunta es :¿como lo puedo hacer?

En angularJS debería ser de la siguiente manera:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/Paneldetencion/app/php/consultaTickets.php',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
        servicio_id: 38
    }
})

.then(function(data) {


var dat = data.data;
$scope.tickets = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
        dat[i]
        var ticket = {
            numero: dat[i].numero,
            rut: dat[i].rut,

        };
        $scope.tickets.push(ticket);
    } 

}
```

es un entero el numero, como debe ir parseado?

error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/....php on line 7`

Comment: Puedes dejar el codigo AngularJs?

Comment: listo eh subido el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

despues de probar llego a la siguiente solución :

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','prueba')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $id = $request->servicio_id;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE id=".$id;
    mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array[] = array(
            "id" => $row["id"],
            "sucursal_id" => $row["sucursal_id"],
            "nombre" => $row["nombre"],
            "nombre_completo" => $row["nombre_completo"]
        ); 
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Modifique el codigo de la conexión a la base de datos ya que probe en mi xampp con php 7.0 y las que ocupas tu estan obsoletas en esa versión.

Cambie la query por

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$id = $request->servicio_id;
$query = "SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE id=".$id;
```

Al enviar desde tu AngularJS tu estas haciendo un POST

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
},
```

Con estos headers por lo tanto estas predimentando que la data que se envia es de tipo `JSON` y PHP no esta recibiendo un `$_POST` como corresponde.

Por eso cuando intentabamos imprimir `$_POST['servicio_id']` siempre recibiamos un index undefined

Comment: PHP/5.6.24 version le pondre la 7.0

Comment: Me avisas! Este codigo esta probado y funciona perfecto para tu necesidad!

Comment: en el controller le mando id como esta definido verdad?

Comment: Si tal cual lo tenias tu en tu codigo AngularJs en el data.

Comment: resulta al 99% me muestra la letra del id pero en id me muestra nullo con este error: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: id in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Paneldetencion/app/php/consultaServicios.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
[{"id":null,"identificador":"P"}]

Comment: Que error muestra @HernanHumaña

Comment: @HernanHumaña recuerda que mi consulta es distinta a la tuya, debes ver que en tu SELECT no estes devolviendo la Id de tu tabla, debes modificar el array que armas acorde a tus datos lo que yo puse fue porque hice un SELECT *, pero tu select solo devuelve rut y numero

Comment: Tu quieres mostrar solo identificador por lo tanto en el array no debes buscar `row['id']`

Comment: Solucionado, Gracias de corazón!

Comment: @HernanHumaña me alegro! Recuerda marcar la respuesta ! Saludos de Chile!

Answer (score 3):

No se ve que el problema sea `AngularJS` sino de como capturas los parámetros desde `PHP`.

Imagino que algo como:

```
$servicioId = $_POST["servicioId"];
```

debiera servirte suponiendo que el parámetro que envíes sea de nombre `servicioId`.

Pero eso no va a ser suficiente ya que además debes enlazar ese valor para que sea incluido en la consulta.

Este [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) te puede servir.

Comment: en caso de que sea in INT como de de ir la petición?